# A tool tip for scraping in php

Tags: php, screen-scraping, mining

Any scraping tool for php?
I would like to extract data from html pages using php, tested some tools but without much success.

Comment: This is an English language site. Please post in English, or ask your question at [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) instead. Good luck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score -2, accepted):

use phpquery
very useful, it is based on the jquery.
One of the 'shortcuts' is `pq()`  which is similar of `$` do jquery